# Compare two and more object key value pair in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to compare different answer sets of the users with the correct answer set and calculate point for every question and allocate/calculate points at the respective index of that question for every question.

My function looks like this:

```js
function evaluateUsersAnswers() {
    let point = 10;
    let double = 20; //selected double powerup(points)
    let NN = 0; //select no negative powerup(points), NN=no negative
    let NP = -5; //not selected any powerup(points), NP=no powerup

    const correctAnsSet = {"0":"a","1":"b","2":"a","3":"a","4":"b","5":"c","6":"a","7":"b","8":"c","9":"c"};

    const user1AnswerSet = {"0":"a","1":"b","2":"b","3":"b","4":"a","5":"c","6":"b","7":"b","8":"c","9":"c"};
    const user1PowerUpSet = {"0":[double],"1":[NN],"2":[double],"3":[NN],"4":[NN],"5":[NN],"6":[NP],"7":[NP],"8":[NP],"9":[double]};

    const user2AnswerSet = {"0":"b","1":"b","2":"b","3":"b","4":"b","5":"a","6":"b","7":"a","8":"c","9":"b"};
    const user2PowerUpSet = {"0":[double],"1":[NN],"2":[double],"3":[NN],"4":[NN],"5":[NN],"6":[NP],"7":[NP],"8":[NP],"9":[double]};

    const user1PointsSet = {};
    const user2PointsSet = {};

    if((Object.values(user1PowerUpSet) === double) || (Object.values(user1PowerUpSet) === NN) || (Object.values(user1PowerUpSet) === NP)) {

    }
}
```

So I want to compare `user1AnswerSet` and `user2AnswerSet` with `correctAnsSet` and I also want to calculate points of `user1` and `user2` based on their correct answer for each question and store it in `user1PointsSet` and `user2PointsSet` object.

Suppose for `user1` 1st question it matches with `correctAnsSet` and for 1st question he/she uses "double" powerup, so his points will be 20 and if it did not match then point will be -20. similarly for `NN` (non-negative power up used by user), if answer matches then point alloted for that question will be 10 and if it does not match then point will be 0. Similarly for `NP` (no power Up used by user), if it matches then point will be given as 10 for correct answer and for incorrect answer point will be -5.

Finally, I want to store their points (i.e for `user1` and `user2`) in `user1PointsSet` object and `user2PointsSet` object respectively. It might be the case that I have multiple user answer sets.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Share your code if you tried anything

Comment: i have figured out the logic behind this problem but not able to figure out how i will write the code. I am stuck. One code i tried but its not working. Please help with the code. Thank you

Comment: [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) returns an Array. It cannot be identical (`===`) to a number. Ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your point weights/types should be strings or just their multiplier number value.

Not entirely sure how your point values get applied, but you can determine of the answer is correct and then apply the point multiplier inside of a switch.

```js
const answerKey = {
  questions: [ "a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "c" ],
  pointValue : 10
};

var users = [{
  id: "user-1",
  answers: [
    { choice : "a", weight : 'double' },
    { choice : "b", weight : 'NN'     },
    { choice : "a", weight : 'double' },
    { choice : "a", weight : 'NN'     },
    { choice : "b", weight : 'NN'     },
    { choice : "c", weight : 'NN'     },
    { choice : "a", weight : 'NP'     },
    { choice : "b", weight : 'NP'     },
    { choice : "c", weight : 'NP'     },
    { choice : "c", weight : 'double' }
  ]
}, {
  id: "user-2",
  answers: [
    { choice : "a", weight : 'double' },
    { choice : "b", weight : 'NN'     },
    { choice : "b", weight : 'double' },
    { choice : "b", weight : 'NN'     },
    { choice : "a", weight : 'NN'     },
    { choice : "c", weight : 'NN'     },
    { choice : "b", weight : 'NP'     },
    { choice : "b", weight : 'NP'     },
    { choice : "c", weight : 'NP'     },
    { choice : "c", weight : 'double' }
  ]
}];

let response = evaluateUsersAnswers(answerKey, users);

console.log(response.map(user => JSON.stringify(user)).join('\n'));
console.log(response.map(user => JSON.stringify({
  id    : user.id,
  total : user.points.reduce((total, curr) => total + curr, 0)
})).join('\n'));

function evaluateUsersAnswers(answerKey, users) {
  return users.map(user => {
    return {
      id     : user.id,
      points : user.answers.map((answer, index) => {
        if (answer.choice === answerKey.questions[index]) {
          switch (answer.weight) {
            case 'double':
              return answerKey.pointValue * 2.0;
            case 'NN':
              return answerKey.pointValue * 1.0;
            case 'NP':
              return answerKey.pointValue * 1.5;
          }
        } else {
          switch (answer.weight) {
            case 'double':
              return answerKey.pointValue * -2.0;
            case 'NN':
              return 0;
            case 'NP':
              return answerKey.pointValue * -1.5;
          }
        }
      })
    };
  });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

You can further simply this using a map of weight type to value.

**Note:** The weights can be uncoupled from the answer key.

```js
const answerKey = {
  questions: [ "a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "c" ],
  pointValue : 10,
  weights : {
    'double' : { correct: 2.0, incorrect: -2.0 },
    'NN'     : { correct: 1.0, incorrect:  0.0 },
    'NP'     : { correct: 1.5, incorrect: -1.5 }
  }
};

var users = [{
  id: "user-1",
  answers: [
    { choice : "a", weight : 'double' },
    { choice : "b", weight : 'NN'     },
    { choice : "a", weight : 'double' },
    { choice : "a", weight : 'NN'     },
    { choice : "b", weight : 'NN'     },
    { choice : "c", weight : 'NN'     },
    { choice : "a", weight : 'NP'     },
    { choice : "b", weight : 'NP'     },
    { choice : "c", weight : 'NP'     },
    { choice : "c", weight : 'double' }
  ]
}, {
  id: "user-2",
  answers: [
    { choice : "a", weight : 'double' },
    { choice : "b", weight : 'NN'     },
    { choice : "b", weight : 'double' },
    { choice : "b", weight : 'NN'     },
    { choice : "a", weight : 'NN'     },
    { choice : "c", weight : 'NN'     },
    { choice : "b", weight : 'NP'     },
    { choice : "b", weight : 'NP'     },
    { choice : "c", weight : 'NP'     },
    { choice : "c", weight : 'double' }
  ]
}];

let response = evaluateUsersAnswers(answerKey, users);

console.log(response.map(user => JSON.stringify(user)).join('\n'));
console.log(response.map(user => JSON.stringify({
  id    : user.id,
  total : user.points.reduce((total, curr) => total + curr, 0)
})).join('\n'));

function evaluateUsersAnswers(answerKey, users) {
  return users.map(user => {
    return {
      id     : user.id,
      points : user.answers.map((answer, index) => {
        let correct = answer.choice === answerKey.questions[index];
        let weight = answerKey.weights[answer.weight];
        let multiplier = weight[correct ? 'correct' : 'incorrect'];

        return answerKey.pointValue * multiplier;
      })
    };
  });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: in the terminal its showing this error:  TypeError: users.map is not a function
>      at evaluateUsersAnswers (C:\Users\Aman\Desktop\Predicta_Project\Cloud_Function_Predicta1\functions\index.js:456:18)

Comment: @AmanSingh The `users` needs to be an array, not a single object or scalar value.

Comment: ohk. But the same error is coming : TypeError: users.map is not a function @Mr. Polywhirl

Comment: The following code will work just fine in node, so I am not sure what your issue is. I just ran the code in this online interpreter: [Repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/nodejs) with no issues. Make sure your data is correct.

Comment: Thank You so much. Now its working fine @Mr. Polywhirl